# How correctly adding images to a view?

Tags: android, image, performance, memory, view

I need your advice... How correctly adding image to view? For example to button... 
Currently I add it like: `android:background="@drawable/btnstyle"`

```
<Button 
android:id="@+id/btnNews" 

android:layout_height="45dp" 
android:layout_marginBottom="26dp" 
android:background="@drawable/btnstyle" 
android:text="News" 
android:textColor="#d5d5d5" 
android:textStyle="bold" />
```

**btnstyle.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"> 
<item android:drawable="@drawable/btnpressed" //19.6KB
android:state_pressed="true" /> 

<item android:drawable="@drawable/btn" /> //20.5KB
</selector>
```

......BUT after start my app using TOO much memory ... more then **35 MB** and on some activities it is more than **135MB**

Comment: Is it only because of your button or your application...??

Answer (score 1):

If you're using `<selector>` XML elements, then you should put `android:src="@drawable\btnSelector` instead of `android:background="@drawable/btnstyle` . However, this doesn't concern the memory occupied. Make sure your *btnpressed* image is properly scaled and of proper format. Android prefers plain .png or 9-patch .png (.9.png) images.

Comment: Did you only replace `android:background` with `android:src` or make additional adjustments?

Comment: only replace android:background with android:src

Comment: That's strange. I can vouch that for Android 4.0 and above this way is the proper one. Revert it back to `android:background` if you want, however that is not the cause of your memory issue. Most likely you have memory leak.